# Unity. Смена сцены с последующим восстановлением. "Кнопка продолжить"

Tags: unity3d

В игре есть Main Menu как отдельная сцена, в виду сильной загруженности игровой сцены. В Игровой сцене реализована загрузка сцены меню. Есть ли возможность вернуться в игровую сцену, после перехода в меню? Так, что бы состояние игровой сцены осталось тем же? Понимаю что используется обычно Pefab или сериализация в xml и т. п., однако придётся сохранять всё вручную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы выгружаете сцену, то только сериализация состояния и последующая десериализация при загрузке.
Поэтому лучше сделайте внутреуровневое меню, которое будет появляться по нажатию кнопки "Esc" и поместите в него самое необходимое, в том числе кнопку "В главное меню". При нажатии этой кнопки сообщайте, что несохранённый прогресс будет потерян (как и делают во всех играх). Две панельки и пять кнопок на производительность сильно не повлияют.
Ну, либо, прикручивайте сериализацию - она вам в любом случае понадобится, если вы хотите прогресс сохранять. Я, например, в .json сохраняют данные.

Comment: То есть, если я загружаю другую сцену, бывшая сцена сразу удаляется и восстановить её невозможно? Только ручками через сериализацию и т. п.

Comment: @RodGers, вы можете загружать сцену с модификатором LoadSceneMode.Additive и тогда она добавится, а не заменит текущую сцену. Но тогда вторую нужно будет выгружать уже ручками через вызов метода. Но вообще, да, вариантов нет. Сцена не должна продолжать висеть в памяти, если она была выгружена, иначе потребление оперативы непомерно разрастётся.

Answer (score 0):

Есть старый метод загрузки сцены внутри сцены application.loadleveladditive. Вначале вы можете отдельно использовать отдельную сцену, а потом из основной сцены игры создавать сцену с помощью этого метода. Но рекомендую всё же сделать нормальное сохранение - загрузку.